# How to get value FROM Ajax in index.php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I would like to get the value sent from php via AJAX in php. But i can not get value. Where is my mistake?

It is my functions.js

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".yeni_problem").click(function(){
            var uid = 1;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'admin.php',
                type: "post",
                data: {'uid': uid},
                    success: function(data){
                        // $("#cvb").text(data);
                    },

                statusCode: {
                404: function(){
                alert("admin.php not found");       
                }
            }       

            });

        }); 
    });
```

and it is my php page that, i control sending value in here. The Codes is large but i write small form. Which that when i run the small codes on other folders as other site it does't work.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>HELPDESK</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icon.css">

    </head>
    <body>


    <button class="yeni_problem">Yeni Problem</button>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['uid'])){
        echo "Value:".$_POST['uid'];
    }else{
        echo "<hr>Value not found<br/>";
    }

    var_dump($_POST);

    ?>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <?php
    echo "</body>
        </html>";
    ?>
```

When i click to ".yeni_problem" class i can not get value.

Answer (score 5):

1st- check you include Jquery

2nd- Be sure admin.php page in the same directory with file you called functions.js in if not check its path

3rd- you pass uid  not data so in php use

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['uid'])){
    echo "Value:".$_POST['uid'];
}else{
    echo "Value not found";
}
?>
```

4th: and if you dynamically generate the element with `class="yeni_problem"` .. so use

```
$('body').on('click',".yeni_problem", function(){
```

instead of

```
$(".yeni_problem").click(function(){
```

5th: if `yeni_problem` is a submit button or anchor so you need to use **e.preventDefault();** to prevent page from reloading

```
$(".yeni_problem").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // rest of code here
```

6th: if `yeni_problem` is a form use **.submit()**

```
$(".yeni_problem").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // rest of code here
```

Comment: @TogrulZade remove statusCode   and use .error: function(){} ... but before all of that check your admin.php path  is it in the same directory with functions.js?? or in another folder?

Comment: the pages is same folder. When i add alert(uid); i get 1

Comment: @TogrulZade can you update your question with the php page which include jquery and scripts in it

Comment: Yes i connected to MySQL database. I can get value FROM Database. But i can not get value only FROM Ajax.

Comment: @TogrulZade we not looking for database right now .. we just looking for the connection between ajax and admin.php file .. so please edit your question with php page code which ".yeni_problem" in it

Comment: @TogrulZade did you dynamically generate the element with class ".yeni_problem" ??

Comment: Can i change it. In Where. Please can you write? I can not find... I don't understand that what is dynamically element.

Comment: @TogrulZade dynamically mean you create the element using for loop in php  or append it in js using .append() or html(); ... or you typed it static like you typed it directly like this <button type="button" class="yeni_problem"></button>

Comment: Understood. No it is not dynamically element. So we don't need .on(); But i write with on(); i can not result.

Comment: @TogrulZade please provide how to include your scripts .. I mean if your element with class yeni_problem in index.php .. please edit your question with index.php code

Comment: i included jquery.js and function.js to footer.php and include footer.php to bottom of admin.php.

Comment: @TogrulZade just click on (edit) in the bottom left side in your question

Comment: Yes it is submit button. I added the codes. But but result has not... :(

Comment: @TogrulZade select your code and click on Ctrl+K to convert it to code

Comment: The Codes is large but i write small form. Which that when i run the small codes on other folders as other site it does't work.

Comment: @TogrulZade try to add full url instead of admin.php  ... like   http ://localhost/admin.php

Comment: when i write result with .html() in success: function(); to some #id i get index.php page. and when i use .text() i get index.php html source code. But $_POST['uid'] is written to display.

Comment: http ://localhost/hlpdsk/admin.php http ://localhost/hlpdsk/js/functions.php

Comment: @TogrulZade  use exit(); after echo "Value:".$_POST['uid'];

Comment: there is different folders but i have included all of them one page. (admin.php).

Comment: @TogrulZade or try to use ../admin.php  instead of just admin.php in $.ajax

Comment: i wrote also this form. And i moved they to same folder. But it doesnt change anything.

Comment: @TogrulZade just advice .. code control the files not files control the code .. I meant don't ever never change your files places or folders .. just find the right code to control this files .. in the beginning we walk in direction and after you trying to move and move files  we have to go to another direction .. so what can we do now??

Comment: i understand but the problem is not files location. It is easy control about file folder location. The problem is other thing.

Comment: May be that my server support JQuery but does't support Ajax? Because i can use JQuery but i can't use only AJAX Result

Comment: @TogrulZade may be ... but try to make a very basic simple example  with index.php and file.js and another php file .make it separately outside your website code . if everything works good so nothing wrong with your server .. if something goes wrong just contact customer service to check that

Comment: I realize that, ajax to send me value but i can't print wirh echo. I inserted coming values to MySQL and they was inserted. and When i print on functions.js with success: function($("#cvb").html(uid)); then it import my index.php to index.php. and when i use .text() then insert index.php html source. I can not normal value as example $user = 'Admin'; ---- We solved to there :)

Comment: I found my mistake. When i write like this: success: function(result){$("#cvb").text(result);} Then insert index.php html source. But when i use empty success: function(){$("#cvb").text(result)} . But when i write success: function(){$("#cvb").text(result)} then i get only my sending value. and i can insert this value to MySQL. But i wanna send mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '".ajax_sending value."';"); in this time i can not write the Query result in index.php. I can write only my sending value from functions.js

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to your code: in the JS snippet, the parameter passed to the server is "uid", which means your server will be getting a `$_POST` array with a position labeled "UID".

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["uid"])){
        echo "Value:".$_POST["uid"];
    }else{
        echo "Value not found";
    }
?>
```

You should also check what is in the `$_POST` variable, insert `var_dump($_POST)` and comment out the rest of the code.

Comment: I get array(0) { } after adding var_dump($_POST). I cannot chek ajax on JS Snippet.

Comment: If you're getting an empty array, then your AJAX is not `POST`ing. Check the URL you're passing to the AJAX call, and also try to `POST` using `XMLHttpRequest`.